# Search site with getElementById using Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, internet-explorer

I'm trying to search some site by writing what I want to search on a cell.

I can't find the ID of the search box for getElementById.

When I press F12 and go to this search box I can get the name, tile, align, class, style, onkeyup, onproperychange, type and Size.

This is the code:

```
Dim objIE as Object
Set objIE = CreateObject("internetexplorer.application")
objIE.Visible = True
objIE.navigate "https://......."
Do While objIE.Busy = True Or objIE.readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop
OBJIE.doxument.getElementsByName("txtNumber")(0).Value = "ajwh"
```

The error is in the getElement line.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please share the code that you have written so far as well as either the snippet of the HTML code that you are interested in, or the url of the corresponding web page. Also please keep in mind that not all elements in an HTML document have an ID. You might need to use a different approach.

Answer (score 0):

You said that you are able to find the **Name** of that Search Box. So you should try to access it with it's name from VBA code.

Below is the sample VBA code:

```
Sub demo()
    Dim IE As Object
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

    IE.Visible = True
    IE.Navigate ("C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\search_demo1.html")
     Do While IE.Busy
        Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)
    Loop

    IE.document.getElementsByName("search2")(0).Value = ws.Range("A1").Value2
    IE.document.getElementById("submit").Click

End Sub
```

Sample HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<style>
body {
  font-family: Arial;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

form.example input[type=text] {
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 17px;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  float: left;
  width: 80%;
  background: #f1f1f1;
}

form.example button {
  float: left;
  width: 20%;
  padding: 10px;
  background: #2196F3;
  color: white;
  font-size: 17px;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  border-left: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

form.example button:hover {
  background: #0b7dda;
}

form.example::after {
  content: "";
  clear: both;
  display: table;
}
#lbl
{
    color: red;
}
</style>
<script>
function search()
{
    var div = document.getElementById('lbl');
    var div1 = document.getElementsByName('search2')[0].value;

div.innerHTML += 'Searching the results for '+ div1;
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Sample Test</h2>
  <input type="text" placeholder="Search.." name="search2" value="">
  <button type="submit" onclick="search()"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button><br>
  <div id=lbl></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thank you. Now he writes me An error. Object variable Or With Black variable not set.

Comment: Please try to provide detailed information like on which line your got this error and did you made necessary changes in this code to run it on your side? If possible than please try to edit the original post with the sample code you tested on your site.

Comment: You have spelling mistake in this line.  OBJIE.doxument.getElementsByName. It should be OBJIE.document

Comment: In My Real code I spelled It right. I didnt copy and paste It because I wrote this from My Phone and not from My pc.

Comment: Can you post the full error message may help to understand it properly?

Comment: I cant Post A photo because Im new here buy I will right It down:

Comment: Run-time error '-2147467259 (80004005)':                                                   Automation Error                                                                   ?????????? ??? ??????

Comment: Try to use IE.Quit in the last line may help to solve this error.